# How do I link drop down menu option to display local HTML files in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, dropdown, dashboard

I have a requirement to show some JS based plots that I made using some Python libraries, and this particular visualization is not possible to make natively in Tableau. But my dashboard is made with Tableau, and I need to show this visualization in the dashboard. So, I saved the JS-based plots as HTML files, and I can run a localhost server and view them in my dashboard with the Web Page object. However, I have 3 such JS-based plots, and I want to provide a dropdown menu, where the user can click on option A to show the HTML page for plot A, click on option B to show the HTML page for plot B, and click on option C to show the HTML page for plot C. But I can't find a way to link the web pages to the drop down options. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a browser window separately that shows the pages:

1. Open the dashboard that contains the sheets you want to enable the right click on
2. Click the "Worksheet" Menu
3. Click "Actions"
4. Click the "Add Action >" button
5. Click "Go to URL"
6. In the popup that comes up, enter the label for the link under the Name field, Select "Menu" under Run action on, then enter the URL in the box.
7. Select your dashboard in the Dropdown (mine is named Dashboard 1), then check the box next to each sheet that should have the link when right clicked.

[image: Screenshot]

If you want it to display *within* your dashboard and not open a browser separately, you will need to write or find a Tableau extension to do this. As of now, there isn't an extension on the extension gallery for it, but there may be one somewhere on Github.